# Best way to "intercept" result of METAL vertex/fragment shader

Tags: metal, metalkit

I currently have a `MTLTexture` for input and am rendering that piece-wise using a set of 20-30 vertices.  This is currently done at the tail end of my `drawRect` handler of an `MTKView`:

```
[encoder setVertexBuffer:mBuff offset:0 atIndex:0];  // buffer of vertices
[encoder setVertexBytes:&_viewportSize length:sizeof(_viewportSize) atIndex:1];
[encoder setFragmentTexture:inputTexture atIndex:0];
[encoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle vertexStart:0 vertexCount:_vertexInfo.metalVertexCount];
[encoder endEncoding];

[commandBuffer presentDrawable:self.currentDrawable];
[commandBuffer commit];
```

---

However, before doing the final `presentDrawable` I would like intercept the resulting texture (I'm going to send a region of it off to a separate `MTKView`).  In other words, I need access to some manner of an output `MTLTexture` after the `drawPrimitives` call.

**What is the most efficient way to do this?**

One idea is to introduce an additional `drawPrimitives` render to an intermediate output `MTLTexture` instead.  I'm not sure how to do this, but I'd scoop that output texture in the process.  I suspect that this would even be done elsewhere (ie. off-screen).

Then I'd issue a second `drawPrimitives` using a single massive textured quad with that outputTexture and then a `presentDrawable` on it.  That code would exist where my previous code was.

There may be a simple method in the Metal API (that I'm missing) that will allow me to capture an output texture of `drawPrimitives`.

I have looked into using an `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` but there are some issues around that on certain MacOSX hardware.

---

UPDATE#1:
**idoogy**, here is the code you were requesting:

Here is where I create the initial "brightness output" texture... we're mid-flight in a vertex shader to do so:

```
...
[encoder setFragmentTexture:brightnessOutput atIndex:0];
[encoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle vertexStart:0 vertexCount:_vertexInfo.metalVertexCount];
[encoder endEncoding];

for (AltMonitorMTKView *v in self.downstreamOutputs). // ancillary MTKViews
    [v setInputTexture:brightnessOutput];

__block dispatch_semaphore_t block_sema = d.hostedAssetsSemaphore;
[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer) {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(block_sema);
}];

[commandBuffer presentDrawable:self.currentDrawable];
[commandBuffer commit];
```

---

Below, we're in the ancillary view's `drawRect` handler with `inputTexture` as the texture that's being transferred, displaying a subregion of it.  I should mention that this `MTKView` is configured to be drawn as a result of a `setNeedsDisplay` rather than as one with an internal timer:

```
id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> encoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
encoder.label = @"Vertex Render Encoder";
[encoder setRenderPipelineState:metalVertexPipelineState];

// draw main content
NSUInteger vSize = _vertexInfo.metalVertexCount*sizeof(AAPLVertex);
id<MTLBuffer> mBuff = [self.device newBufferWithBytes:_vertexInfo.metalVertices
                                               length:vSize
                                              options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
[encoder setVertexBuffer:mBuff offset:0 atIndex:0];
[encoder setVertexBytes:&_viewportSize length:sizeof(_viewportSize) atIndex:1];
[encoder setFragmentTexture:self.inputTexture atIndex:0];
[encoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle vertexStart:0 vertexCount:_vertexInfo.metalVertexCount];
[encoder endEncoding];

[commandBuffer presentDrawable:self.currentDrawable];
[commandBuffer commit];
```

---

The above code **seems** to work fine.  Having said that, I think we're telling a different story in the Xcode debugger.  It's pretty obvious that I'm wasting huge swaths of time doing things this way... That long command buffer is the ancillary monitor view doing a LOT of waiting...

[image]

Comment: Ugh... is it as simple as this (issued after endEncoding):   id<MTLTexture> currentTexture = [[self currentDrawable] texture];

Comment: And, in my case, I'd need to set framebufferOnly value to false in my case -- so I can reuse the output elsewhere.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to merely read the resulting MTLTexture for use elsewhere, or are you also looking to modify it before it gets presented?

Comment: I was looking to present a subregion of the resulting MTLTexture in an alternate MTKView.

Comment: also wanted to respond to your question above about just taking the current drawable. The issue with that is timing -- that'll never work if you call it after endEncoding, because the GPU is completely asynchronous. It doesn't even start processing your request until you call commit, so the texture won't contain the output yet. That's why you should use waitUntilCompleted or addCompletionHandler().

Comment: Interesting... in my code, I've just run an encoder to handle 0-100% brightness and I set the output of that kernel shader immediately as the input on an ancillary MTKView, drawing a subregion of it.  Then I call presentDrawable, and then commit on the original MTKView.  That seems to work fine for the ancillary view's purposes.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please post some code, demonstrating this?

Comment: I've added some "functional" code, but was profiling it recently also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doable. Before you call `commit` on your `commandBuffer`, add a completion handler for the command buffer by calling `[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:]`, then from within the completion handler, grab the color attachments from your `renderPassDescriptor`.

`renderPassDescriptor` holds the current set of attachments being drawn to, and is configured automatically by `MTKView`. The actual textures rotate per frame because `MTKView` is using triple-buffering to ensure continuous utilization of the GPU, but as long as you're within your completion handler, that particular attachment won't be released for use in a future frame, so you can safely read from it, copy it, etc.

**NOTE:** Make sure to complete your handler reasonably quickly or your frame rate will drop (because `MTKView` will quickly run out of render targets and will just sit there until they are released).

Here's a generic code snippet to get you started:

```
// Grab the current render pass descriptor from MTKView so it's accessible from within the completion block:
__block MTLRenderPassDescriptor *renderPassDescriptor = self.renderPassDescriptor;

[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer) {
   // This will be called once the GPU has completed rendering your frame.
   // This is your output texture:
   id <MTLTexture> outputTexture = renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture;
}];
[commandBuffer commit];
```

Comment: This is great information.  My confusion with your explanation comes in when I want to utilize numerous intermingled kernel/vertex rendering stages -- with the texture output of one stage feeding the next --  in a single command buffer.  Your answer would seem to indicate the need for multiple command buffers and "waiting".  Anecdotally, that's not what I'm experiencing so far.

Comment: Well, that depends on how you use the output from a certain drawing call. If you use it from another command in the same command buffer, that'll be fine. If you're using it elsewhere, you'll have to wait for your command buffer to complete.

Comment: I read that typically you have one command buffer per frame, with multiple render pass descriptors (one fir each "pass"). I guess with `MTKView` you create the "intermediate" rpds and use the one `self.renderPassDescriptor` for the final, render to screen?

Comment: In that case, serialization of the passes shoudl be enforced by the command encoders created from each rpd...? I'm still decoding the "ObjectsExample" project from Apple...